# Generate api documentation without creating rest with swagger2

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I'm new to spring and swagger so I have some difficulties with generating API documentation using swagger. I've done API documentation at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, but I have to export generated API documentation to the other website. Is there a way to generate just json or yml file without displaying documentation at swagger-ui.html?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation